# How can I test items with variable IDs?

Tags: variables, xpath, selenium, selenium-ide, automated-tests

I want to test variable pictures and variable check-boxes in my web page. It is like an online market, so every time you refresh the same page you will get different pictures with different IDs and check-boxes with different IDs too.

I have tried XPath, but it contains an ID so I can't use it every time with the same page:

```
INPUT[@name="data[car.**88535**]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually "list" all your checkboxes with xpath.

Like :

`List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));`

I think you can use the same for your pictures.

So with that you can do something like that :

```
void checkCB(List<WebElement> c) {
    for (WebElement e : c)
        if ("yes".equals(e.getAttribute("checked")))
        Systeme.println("Element is checked");
}
```

(Currently writing with selenium 2.0)

Comment: A slight performance boost would be to be explicit in what type of elements you are looking for. The XPath should *really* be *//input[@type='checkbox']*. Since only `input`'s can have that type, but your XPath would search every single element.